React Native - Not rendering Tabs Component
Using Expo Router. The app doesn't render Tabs navigation component to the screen unless some change is made.
root _layout.tsx  
<Stack
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#f472b6",
          },
          contentStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colorScheme == "dark" ? "#09090B" : "#FFFFFF",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack>

// index.tsx
return (
    <View className="flex-1 bg-background bg-white">
      {/* <Text className='text-red-500'>Hello Chat??</Text> */}
    </View>
      
  );


_layout.tsx in (tabs)
return (
    <Tabs>
        <Tabs.Screen name="activity" options={{ 
            headerShown: false, 
            href: null,
            title: "Activity",
            }} />
        <Tabs.Screen name="profile" options={{ 
            headerShown: false,
            href: null,
            title: "Profile",
            }}  />
            //set icon
        <Tabs.Screen name="chat" options={{ 
            headerShown: false,
            href: null,
            title: "Chat",
            

            }} />
    </Tabs>

current:
Right now it just renders the stack component in root layout and doesn't care to render the tabs.

expected:
when I'm making any changes to the project, it then renders and displays as needed.

